# joomla prepends to 'path'

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

my wife have a joomla 2.5 site

She claims that she has done nothing except, installing and and subsequently uninstalling Koowa plugi, Ninja plugin and Ninjaboard component.

Anyway after that the joomla 'path' have changed such that between the domain name and the path rendered by HTML, the joomla server now seems to insert "/index.php" or "/index.php/menu-item-name"

for example clicking a link like the following:

```
<a href="images/some_folder/xxx.JPG">
```

points to something like: http://www.domain.contry/index.php/fun/images/some_folder/xxx.JPG

how to we change the 'global path settings' such that

```
<a href="images/some_folder/xxx.JPG">
```

points to
http://www.domain.contry/images/some_folder/xxx.JPG

NB: my joomla and php skills are very basic :)

**Update:**

I think the problem something like this:

all the image paths used to be 'absolute' and are now relative, so if I am in 'index.php/some-menu' and click 'images/xxx.jpg' then it resolves to 'index.php/some-menu/images/xxx.jpg', she has all her images in the image folder, is there some way make all image paths 'absolute' instead of relative in joomla?

because changing 'images/xxx.jpg' to '/images/xxx.jpg' with firebug fixes the problem...

if it is not possible in joomla... how bad do you think it is to:
download the sql database
and run a regex akin to

```
s/<.+?=\"(images)\/[\w\s]+?\.[\w\d]+)\".*?>/\/$1/g
```

Comment: Consider using an editor (I much prefer JCE) to add images in the future to prevent this problem. If you do have to revise a large quantity of image paths in your articles, there are Joomla extensions that will more safely allow you to do so without resorting to regexes. Back up the site first! (I use Akeeba.)

Comment: she uses tinyMCE, to upload the images, and all images worked fine (and had been for a year) I will try to install JCE and see if it uploades images properly :)

Comment: Installing JCE won't help. You still have to update all your image paths. Look into an .htaccess redirect using a regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in your global configuration under the Site tab for your SEO settings. Make sure you have URL rewriting enabled, and follow the directions in the tooltip to rename htaccess.txt (Linux servers) or web.config.txt (Windows servers) if necessary.

If you get a server error on the site at this point, try uncommenting `RewriteBase /` in .htaccess.

Comment: Thanks, url rewriting is disabled, I have enabled it and uncommented the "RewriteBase /" line, however the problem still persists... All links/images are broken because of this 'injection', but all page requests are parsed properly...

Comment: That doesn't sound right. Did you clear cache (Joomla and browser)? What's in configuration.php for 'live site'?

Comment: I have updated the post to help you help me further ;), there are all kinds of scary passwords in configuration.php, but of 'paths' there is only a log_path and tmp_path... is there a media_path or something similar flag I can set?, what line are you interested in?

Comment: I asked specifically for the 'live site' entry.

Comment: public $live_site = '';

Comment: You should enable  the SEF plugin, it will take care of adding the base path of the site to the urls that start with "images/..."