# Joomla alters the path of the images included in an article

Tags: image, joomla

I'm new to joomla and doing some changes to an existing website designed using Joomla.
Given below is a line that I've inserted to an existing article

```
<img SRC="images/myimages/demo/IM-0002-0025.jpg" class="highlighted" data-value="image_value"/>
```

but it does not display the image when I view it on website. When I view the source of the image in the webpage it shows below

```
<img src="http://xxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/images/myimages/demo/IM-0002-0025.jpg" class="highlighted mTSThumb" data-value="image_value">
```

My JPATH_BASE is http://localhost/mywebsitename/
but still it appends "http://xxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/" to the image path

I've even enabled the URL rewrite as mentioned in the [joomla prepends to 'path'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18598640/joomla-prepends-to-path)
But still it didn't change anything. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this is a hack or not. but I've managed to fix the issue by specifying the image path followed by a ./
So now the image path looks like this and it works fine.

```
<img SRC="./images/myimages/demo/IM-0002-0025.jpg" class="highlighted" data-value="image_value"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I've used joomla but I'm sure you have to begin the line with a forward slash to before images.

```
<img src="/images/"
```

This makes it relational to the site.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. But still no luck. It alters the image path URL as it did before

Answer (score 0):

Yes that looks right. Mark your answer as complete